# Help me find this Drarry Fic please

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, drarry

It is set during 8th year I believe. Draco is on the line and Harry tries to help him but around the time they start dating Crabbe calls Harry a f*g, Draco then tackles him in retaliation.

In the next few days Draco gets arrested. Harry outs them by kissing Draco in the hall while he is getting arrested. Harry and the golden trio save Draco from going to Azkaban.